# issue with Microsoft translator java api

Tags: java, microsoft-translator

I was searching around for a free *translation* API for Java, I found  [microsoft-translator-java-api](https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-java-api), it is very easy to use I liked that, but when I translate from ***English*** to ***Arabic*** like :

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {       

    // Set the Client ID / Client Secret once per JVM. It is set statically and applies to all services
    Translate.setClientId("MY_CLIENT_ID_KEY");
    Translate.setClientSecret("MY_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY");

    // From English-> Arabic
    String translatedText = Translate.execute("When creating a text field component, it’s common to specify some initial text and/or a number of columns from which the field’s width is calculated.", Language.ENGLISH, Language.ARABIC);

    System.out.println(" English -> Arabic: " + translatedText);

}
```

I get out put on console as :

```
 English -> Arabic : ??? ????? ???? ??? ??? ?????? ?????? ??? ???? ??????? ?/?? ??? ?? ??????? ???? ?? ?????? ??? ???? ????? ?????.
```

I m confused how to get this bug fixed so that I can get Some meaning full characters on the console instead of that above.

Comment: Your console is displaying the wrong codepage or font.  This has nothing to do with Java or your code.

Comment: OK but when I show that in a JSP page then I get the same characters as well !!!

Comment: You're probably serving the page with the wrong encoding.  Check the Encoding menu in your browser.

Comment: Thanks Man! in JSP I have fixed that, but how to fix that in console please any help :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the encoding of the console to `UTF-8` then the Arabic characters will be correctly displayed.
If you are using eclipse do the steps below:

#### Step 1:

> Click Run --> Run Configurations..

[image]

#### Step 2:

> Click on the Common tab -> select Other -> Change encoding to UTF-8

[image]

#### Step 3:

Click apply and the Arabic text can now be printed on the console.